# Possible methodology for putative combination of different statistics and metrics for ranking of functional enrichment analysis results

Tags: p-value, algorithms, fishers-exact-test

i would like to ask a general statistical question concering the ranking of some  functional enrichment analysis results, regardless of technology (rna-seq, microarrays, etc), or methodology (GSEA, etc). For instance, assume that i have some results from an overepresentation analysis, with some terms, along with fisher's exact test p-values, as also the relevant jaccard coefficient for each result. I wonder (and please excuse me for any "naive" question as a molecular biologist), is there a mathematical or statistical way of combining these two measures, into an aggregated score ? that is, the p-values with the jaccard score? To somehow take both of them into account ?